# Android , reading files from folder using relative path

Tags: android

I am creating folder X in my android app , which has list of files .This list needs to   displayed to user for selection , Whats the relative path used to access list of files located   in folder X. I tried /X , ./X but it does not not return the list of files in  that folder.

Asset can one of the option , but when i created new folders under asset folder , it did not recognize it , i.e getAssets().list("") did not return these new folders??? aren new folders allowed in asset ? do we have to stick to image ,sound and webkit?

Thanks
Kavitha

Comment: And how exactly are you creating that folder and where?

Comment: Right now i am trying to add folder under assets folder,  say assets/X1 but when you getAssets().list("") did does not list X1 and also when use getAssets().list("X1") it will not return the files in it cause it doesn ot recognize it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asset folder was the way to go , we can create multiple sub folders and also place the files we want .Using asset manager we can specify relative path and list files and open files.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to do, you probably want to use either the internal or the external data storage.

The internal storage is located inside the /data/data/your_app/ folder, although you should not need to use that path at all. Following the example:

```
String FILENAME = "hello_file";
String string = "hello world!";

FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
fos.write(string.getBytes());
fos.close();
```

You can see that the files will path is relative to the internal storage. Thus, you can create your folder with no additional path.

If, on the other side, you would prefer to write to an sdcard (external storage), then you should use:

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory ()` (`getExternalFilesDir()` in APIs >= 8) as your root, and all other paths should be relative to it.

The examples were taken verbatim from the dev guide: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: Files are stored and packed with .apk file , i want just access that folder created to read and parse the file , the options specified are not feasible for this

Comment: Then, you will probably be using the assets folder. There is no path to access them directly as a regular file. Instead, you will need to use getAssets() (see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getAssets%28%29)

Comment: Ummm , there is no way i can list the files in assets folder , if need to specify the file name if i need to parse it , but i want the user to select the files from the ones present in the folder.Reading folder with in project seems so complicated

Comment: If the files won't change, just make a string array to list the file names. Alternatively, you can copy all the files to the internal storage upon first run.

Comment: Asset can one of the option , but when i created new folders under asset folder , it did not recognize it , i.e getAssets().list("") did not return these new folders??? aren new folders allowed in asset ? do we have to stick to image ,sound and webkit?

Comment: Did you clean the project and rebuild? That line should return your folder/files list under /assets